# Is the Game Night riddle nonsense?

Tags: game-night

In Game Night they play a murder mystery game for which they have to solve riddles. Following riddle was read out, but the solution was not revealed during the movie.

> I’m brown and old by day, white and young by night. My eyes are glass. I have nine faces but no head. I sing to the sky but have no voice. I’m everywhere and nowhere.

Is there a solution for this riddle in Game Night or is it nonsense? I'm looking for a quote or similar that says if it's solvable, not the actual solution.

P.S. Please avoid discussing potential solutions. You can find such discussions via internet search.

Comment: It is nonsense to make the game go as it was planned

Comment: @TK-421 I think I understand what you're driving at. That could be a good answer if you elaborate it further.

Comment: I've twitted at the scriptwriter. Hopefully he'll respond